# Is there a way to have two columns in the Gnome launcher?

Tags: 18.04, gnome, launcher

I would like to have an application launcher bar with two columns, is this achievable somehow?

Currently I use [ArcMenu](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1228/arc-menu/) as a workaround to access some more tools quickly, but two columns of visible icons would just be great.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Rofi](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/rofi.1.html).

```
#!/bin/bash 

 rofi \
    -show drun \
    -show-icons \
    -columns 3 \
    -width 90 \
    -drun-match-fields "exec"
```

Bind the script to a convenient keyboard shortcut.

### Rofi-based application launcher

[image: Rofi-based application launcher]

In the script, I've used three columns but you can change that to two and adjust the width to your taste. To launch an application which has a `.desktop` file in `~/.local/share/applications` or in `/usr/share/applications`, highlight the application via the keyboard or mouse or by typing a few letters in the search box and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

You can also specify the icon theme of your choice as mentioned in `man rofi`:

> -show-icons
>
> Show application icons in drun and window modes.
>
> -drun-icon-theme
>
> Specify icon theme to be used in drun mode if show-icons setting is enabled. If not specified default theme from DE is used, Adwaita and gnome themes act as fallback themes.

You can preview and select rofi themes from your terminal using the command `rofi-theme-selector`.

---

Rofi works in all desktop environments with x11.